# Passing Variable to page.evaluate() function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to pass a variable I am using in my code into page.evaluate function, but it's console.logging as it's not defined and creating errors for my code.

```
const putterID = puttersObjectArray[putterPriorityIndexFound].id;
console.log(putterID) // 7729

    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        console.log(putterID)
        await fetch(`https://www.examplestore.com/store/product/addtocartplp/?productId=${putterID}&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1647970037149`, {
            "headers": {
            "accept": "*/*",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"99\"",
            "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
            "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
            "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
            "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
            "x-newrelic-id": "VQABWFZUCBAEXFRRAQkCVVc=",
            "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
            },
            "referrer": "https://www.examplestore.com/store/products/",
            "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
            "body": null,
            "method": "GET",
            "mode": "cors",
            "credentials": "include"
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    });
```

I get the following error: `(node:3210) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: putterID is not defined`

Comment: replace the first line inside of `page.evaluate` to `console.log(typeof putterID)`.. does it return `undefined`?

Comment: Yeah, `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I need to pass putterID in like this:

```
const putterID = puttersObjectArray[putterPriorityIndexFound].id;
console.log(putterID) // 7729

    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        console.log(putterID)
        await fetch(`https://www.examplestore.com/store/product/addtocartplp/?productId=${putterID}&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1647970037149`, {
            "headers": {
            "accept": "*/*",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"99\"",
            "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
            "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
            "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
            "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
            "x-newrelic-id": "VQABWFZUCBAEXFRRAQkCVVc=",
            "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
            },
            "referrer": "https://www.examplestore.com/store/products/",
            "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
            "body": null,
            "method": "GET",
            "mode": "cors",
            "credentials": "include"
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, putterID);
```

Comment: what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this. Here, i have first check for putterId then it will execute async code.

```js
const putterID = puttersObjectArray[putterPriorityIndexFound].id;
putterID && page.evaluate(async () => {
        console.log(putterID)
        await fetch(`https://www.examplestore.com/store/product/addtocartplp/?productId=${putterID}&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1647970037149`, {
            "headers": {
            "accept": "*/*",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"99\"",
            "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
            "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
            "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
            "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
            "x-newrelic-id": "VQABWFZUCBAEXFRRAQkCVVc=",
            "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
            },
            "referrer": "https://www.examplestore.com/store/products/",
            "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
            "body": null,
            "method": "GET",
            "mode": "cors",
            "credentials": "include"
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

const putterID = puttersObjectArray[putterPriorityIndexFound].id;
console.log(putterID) // 7729

```
await page.evaluate(async (putterID) => {
    console.log(putterID)
    await fetch(`https://www.examplestore.com/store/product/addtocartplp/?productId=${putterID}&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1647970037149`, {
        "headers": {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"99\"",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "x-newrelic-id": "VQABWFZUCBAEXFRRAQkCVVc=",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
        },
        "referrer": "https://www.examplestore.com/store/products/",
        "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
        "body": null,
        "method": "GET",
        "mode": "cors",
        "credentials": "include"
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

Comment: ate(async (putterID) =>  See here pass putterId in function

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I tried that before, it is still `undefined.`